# Ansible -- approach to hierarchical management of variables

Tags: ansible

This a common case, but it doesn't seem straight-forward in Ansible.

Let's assume of a hierarchy of groups:
   linux-hosts:
     application-hosts:
        foobar-application-hosts:
           foobar01

Now for each of these groups we want to define a set of cron jobs.

For linux-hosts, jobs that run on all linux hosts.
For application-hosts, jobs that run on only application hosts.
For foobar-applciation-hosts, jobs that run on only foobar-applcation-hosts.

The variable name is `cronjobs`, say, and it's a list of cron module settings.

By default, the foobar-application-hosts would clobber the setting for anything above it.  Not good.

I don't see an easy way to merge (on a specific level).  So I thought, all right, perhaps Ansible exposes the individual group variables for the groups a host belongs to during a run.  There is groups, and there is group_names, but I don't see a groupvars corresponding to hostvars.

This seems to imply I either use to some mix-and-match of cycling over groups, dynamically importing vars (if possible), and doing the merge myself.  Perhaps putting some of this in a role.  But this feels like such a hack.  Is there another approach?

Answer (score 0):

Groups in the Ansible sense is a "tag" on hosts. Hosts can belong to more than one group. So, the conjobs var should be a list, with the same length as the number of groups that the host is in.